# A view to add and remove items from a collection on the same view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, begincollectionitem

I'm creating a View that allows the user to add and remove objects in list in a particular way that the client wants. The user has to be able to add or remove multiple forms on the page before submitting. When the page posts it needs to display what's already in the list, with the option to remove each item, plus allow the user to add/remove more objects before submitting again.

I'm able to use JQuery and a Partial View to let the user add or remove new forms before submitting. What I can't figure out is how to provide a button to remove objects that are already in the list from a previous submit.

Can anyone help me out with this? It would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I've figured out so far. 
In my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="recipients">
        @foreach (var p in Model)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_Recipient", p)
        }

        <div id="recipients0"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="add" type="button">Add</button>
    <button id="remove" type="button">Remove</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#add').click(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("Recipient")';
        var div = $('#recipients');
        var divlast = $('div[id^="recipients"]:last');

        var num = parseInt(divlast.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1;


        var newdiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'recipients' + num)//rest of code

        $.get(url, function (response) {
            div.append(newdiv);
            newdiv.append(response);
        });
    })
    $('#remove').click(function () {
        var div = $('#recipients');
        var divlast = $('div[id^="recipients"]:last');
        var num = parseInt(divlast.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10);
        alert("div[id='recipients" + num + "']");
        $("div[id='recipients" + num + "']").remove();
        //div.remove('div[id^="recipients' + num + '"]');
    })
```

The Partial View with the form to add data to a new object:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("recipients"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Recipient)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Recipient)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Recipient)
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Amount)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Amount)


}
<td>
    @Ajax.ActionLink(
        "Remove",
        "Remove",
        "CashRecipients",

        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = "onDeleteSuccess"
        }
    )
</td>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

<script>
    var onDeleteSuccess = function (result) {
        alert('Howdy');
    };
</script>
```

My controller:

```
    public PartialViewResult Recipient()
    {
        return PartialView("_Recipient", new CashRecipientViewModel());
    }

    // GET: 
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<CashRecipientViewModel> model = new List<CashRecipientViewModel>();

        return View(model);
    }

    // POST: CashRecipients/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Amount,Recipient")] IEnumerable<CashRecipientViewModel> recipients)
    {

        return View(recipients);

    }
```

My View Model:

```
public class CashRecipientViewModel
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the name of the recipient")]
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You have not shown the partial (I assume you using `BeginCollectionItem()`). And what is the point of the `id` attributes for the enclosing`<div>` elements (that is unnecessary). I why do you not have a delete button associated with each element (what of the user wants to delete the 3rd one in a list of 10?)

Comment: I edited the question to add the partial. The id attributes for the enclosing div elements are for the jquery for the remove button at the bottom. And including a delete button associated with each element is exactly what I'm asking how to do.

Comment: You can see it running here: http://dynamicform.azurewebsites.net/CashRecipients/Create  The remove button at the bottom works to remove forms before they are submitted. The remove actionlinks in the partial view are currently calling an empty method...I can't figure out how to get scope on the list from there.

Comment: You have not shown the partial (with the `BeginCollectionItem()` and the form controls for editing the model. And you do not, (and should not) be generating `id` attributes for those divs. You partial needs a button with a class name and you handle the buttons click event to remove the associated form controls (and in the case of existing items, call server method using ajax to delete it, or 'flag' the model for deletion)

Comment: Sorry, left out part of the Partial View code; edited to add it. Please look at how the main view JQuery is using those id attributes - it makes sense. Calling a server method using ajax is what the action link in the partial is already doing. I just can't figure out how to pass the whole list.

Comment: No it does not make sense :) - you use relative selectors (your writing a whole lot of unnecessary code). No time just now, but will add answer in 30-40 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a single 'remove' button does not make sense and you need a 'remove' associated with each item in the collection. In addition, remove the `id` attributes from your `<div>` elements and use relative selectors.

Change the partial to

```cs
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("recipients"))
{
    <div class="item" data-id="@Model.ID"> // add an enclosing element
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Recipient)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Recipient)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Recipient)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Amount)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Amount)
        <button type="button" class="remove">Remove</button> // add button
    </div>
}
```

The in the main view, your scripts will be

```cs
var url = '@Url.Action("Recipient")';
var recipients = $('#recipients');
$('#add').click(function () {
    $.get(url, function (response) {
        recipients.append(response);
    });
});
$('#recipients').on('click', '.remove', (function() {
    var container = $(this).closest('.item');
    var id = container.data('id');
    if (!id) {
        container.remove();
    } else {
        // see notes below
    }
}
```

For any items that have been added in the view, the value of property `ID` will be `null` and the code in the `if` block will remove the item from the view. However for existing items that you may be editing (where the `ID` has a value), then you need to consider how to remove it from the database. Options include

1. Adding an additional property in the view model (say) `public bool
   IsDeleted { get; set; }` and including a hidden input in the partial
   for it. You could then set it to `true` so when you submit, you can
   delete all `recipients.Where(x => x.IsDeleted);`

   ```cs
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsDeleted, new { @class = "flag" })

   } else {
       container.find('.flag').val('true');
   }
   ```
2. Making an ajax call to a server method which deletes the item from
   the database, and if successful, remove the associated container
   from the DOM

   ```cs
   } else {
       $.post(yourDeleteUrl, { id: id }, function(response) {
           if(response) {
               container.remove()
           } else {
               // oops, something went wrong
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: This is good, however the enclosing div in the partial never gets an ID, so the else block never runs.

Comment: You don't need it for 'new' items (the `data-id="@Model.ID"` is only applicable when you editing existing items - the code in the `else` block only applies to deleting existing items)

Comment: This works as-is and without even needing the IsDeleted flag or ajax call, since the list gets constituted from the view on post. I can just update the database from the list at that time. I'd only need to use the if statement that checks !ID if I want to remove the item from the list *before* submit (in case the page gets reloaded by the user before they submit it).

Comment: I understand that, but even existing items don't seem to have an id. I can by putting in some alerts that the else block never gets run, even for existing items.

Comment: What do you mean they do not have an ID - if you have created some and saved then to the database, and then come back later to edit them, then they must have an ID

Comment: I can only assume that when your initializing the view models for existing items, you did not set the ID property based on the data models

Comment: Right now this test program isn't using a database at all. I'm just working with the view model. Are you saying that when I construct a new view model object, I need to create a data model object in the db to back it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128015/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-robert-m).