# Deleting items from dynamic list ASP Core MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dynamic-list

I'm trying to remove or hide items from a list and I'm facing two problems, 1- the newly cannot be removed, 2- Tried to tag the deleted items as isDeleted = true using Javascript then later delete them in the controller following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40572625/10773318 but it didn't work.

Here's my view models

```
 public class CreateEditParentViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<ChildViewModel> ChildrenLists { get; set; }
}

    public class ChildViewModel
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool isDeleted { get; set; } 
}
```

In the main view

```
    <div id="editorRows">
    @foreach (var item in Model.ChildrenLists)
    {
        <partial name="_RowPartial" model="item" />
    }
    </div>
<a id="addItem" asp-action="BlankRow" asp-controller="Home">Add Row...</a> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Finished" />
```

The javascript in the main view

```
@section scripts {
<script>
    $("#addItem").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("a.deleteRow").click(function () {
        $(this).parents("div.editorRow:first").remove(); //does not work with newly added
        return false;
    }); //what it should do: hide and set isDeleted = true if id is not null - remove if null
</script>
```

Finally the partial view

```
<div class="editorRow">
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ChildrenLists"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.isDeleted)
    <span>Name: </span> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name);
}
<a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1- the newly cannot be removed

You can manually bind `click` event handler for the new generated `<a href="#" class="deleteRow">` element, like below.

```
success: function (html) {
    $("#editorRows").append(html);

    $("a.deleteRow").bind("click", function () {
        //...
        //code logic here
    });
}
```

> 2- Tried to tag the deleted items as isDeleted = true using Javascript

To achieve the requirement, you can refer to the following code snippet.

```
<script>
    $("#addItem").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#editorRows").append(html);

                $("a.deleteRow").bind("click", function () {
                    del_row($(this));
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("a.deleteRow").click(function () {

        del_row($(this));
           
        return false;
    }); 

    function del_row(el) {
        console.log("del");
        console.log($(el).siblings("input[id$='__Id']").val());
        var childitem_id = $(el).siblings("input[id$='__Id']").val();

        if (childitem_id == 0 || childitem_id == "") {
            $(el).parent("div.editorRow").remove();  
        } else {
            $(el).siblings("input[id$='__isDeleted']").val("true");
            $(el).parent("div.editorRow").hide();
        }

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly!! Thank you very much, you've saved me. I spent days of learning and trying for this little issue, really thankful.